# Decoding not reversing unicode encoding in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, encoding, character-encoding, minidom

Ok, I have a hardcoded string I declare like this

```
name = u"Par Catégorie"
```

I have a # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- magic header, so I am guessing it's  converted to utf-8

Down the road it's outputted to xml through

```
xml_output.toprettyxml(indent='....', encoding='utf-8')
```

And I get a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Most of my data is in French and is ouputted correctly in CDATA nodes, but that one harcoded string keep ... I don't see why an ascii codec is called.

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `coding` header in your source file tells Python what encoding your *source* is in. It's the encoding Python uses to decode the source of the unicode string literal (`u"Par Catégorie"`) into a unicode object. The unicode object itself has no encoding; it's raw unicode data. (Internally, Python will use one of two encodings, depending on how it was configured, but Python code shouldn't worry about that.)

The UnicodeDecodeError you get means that somewhere, you are mixing unicode strings and bytestrings (normal strings.) When mixing them together (concatenating, performing string interpolation, et cetera) Python will try to convert the bytestring into a unicode string by decoding the bytestring using the default encoding, ASCII. If the bytestring contains non-ASCII data, this will fail with the error you see. The operation being done may be in a library somewhere, but it still means you're mixing inputs of different types.

Unfortunately the fact that it'll work just fine as long as the bytestrings contain just ASCII data means this type of error is all too frequent even in library code. Python 3.x solves that problem by getting rid of the implicit conversion between unicode strings (just `str` in 3.x) and bytestrings (the `bytes` type in 3.x.)

Comment: bingo. I was indeed mixing a bytestring and unicode string somewhere. I guess I should always use unicode strings.

Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong parameter name? From [the doc](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toprettyxml), I can see the keyword argument name is supposed to be `encoding` and not `coding`.

Comment: i edited the question, but I use the right param name. just solve the problem. for some reason, in the shell i get 

>>> u'catégorie'.encode('utf-8')
'cat\xc3\xa9gorie'
>>> 'cat\xc3\xa9gorie'.decode('utf-8')
u'cat\xe9gorie'

So I was worried that the string would not be ouputted correctly to xml. wrong assumption.